# Change Smart Contract Languages after few versions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am experimenting with Hyperledger Fabric and am not sure what the best smart contract language to start.
That being said, I did start with JS using the [Commercial Paper example](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html).

**Can you change smart contract language along the way?**
For example, you write the first few version of your contract in JS and then you switch to GO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change chaincode language as you go. Just make sure the same chaincode is installed on all the peers.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is to write in a supported programming language that is fast for you. This allows rapid prototyping and demonstration. If it works out, rewrite in a compiled language, such as Go, which also has the benefit of stronger typing.